# VB.NET : Use System.Type in value binding

Tags: vb.net, reflection, binding, system.type

I am trying to use reflections in VB.NET to handle types.

```
    Public Function reflective(Of T)() As System.Type
        Dim t_ As T = Nothing
        Return t_.GetType()
    End Function
 
    Sub Main()
        Dim nbr_type As Type = reflective(Of Int32)() 'Works fine
        Console.Writeline("Number type is: " & nbr_type.Name) 'Works fine
        Dim nbr As nbr_type = Nothing 'Fails 'nbr_type' is not declared. It may be inac...
        'VB compiler completely fails to understand what I am trying to do
    End Sub
```

How do I initialize a variable using `System.Type`?

Comment: You can simply write `Return GetType(T)`. No need to create a variable. See [Activator.CreateInstance Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Firstly, you don't need that `reflective` function at all. Just use `Dim nbt_type = GetType(Int32)`.

Comment: Secondly, you need to get a better understanding of how Reflection works. A `Type` object is not a data type. It is an object that contains information about a data type. You can't use a variable that refers to a `Type` object where a data type is expected. How could that possibly make sense? That object doesn't exist until run time but you're expecting the compiler to understand it at compile time. Not happening. Once you start using Reflection, you have to keep using it. That means that everything is type `Object` and you use Reflection to create instances and access members.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But note that you can forcibly convert to a known type at boundaries; that is, depending on what you want to do in `reflective(Of T)`, you might have a routine doing reflection internally on `Object` and then doing a `DirectCast` to change a result to a `T`.  Or you might have a variable that is always type `T` but use reflection to access its properties or methods.